# Datatable 1.9.4 Error to edit row not visibile for pagination

Tags: datatable

I ha ve a problem to update some row in a table if some of this are not visible for pagination. Console log give me this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined". Here there is my code http://live.datatables.net/vuxedaqu/3/edit

Answer (score 0):

I find it... Here the solution... http://live.datatables.net/bilizube/1/edit